# How to use ocg-p with LuaLaTeX (TeXlive 2015)?

Tags: luatex, ocg, ocg-p

If I compile the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{ocg-p}%Layers
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

with luaLaTeX, it stops with the following error:

```
! Package ocg-p Error: pdfeTeX, version >= 1.20, required.
```

The [ocg-p package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p) is supported only for pdflatex and xelatex, 
but in the past (TeXLive 2014) I had no problems to use it in combination 
with luaLaTeX.

I need the combination of ocg-p and luaLaTeX.

The [ocg-p-package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p) itself is unchanged since 2013, so this check for pdfeTeX-version already existed in the previous version.

Comment: `ocgx2` fully replaces `ocg-p` and fixes a few bugs (e. g. non-functional `dvips` support).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package `ocgx2` serves as a drop-in replacement for `ocg-p`, `ocg` and `ocgx`packages.

See [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx2/README) for fixes and additions in comparison with the other packages.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ocgx2} %pdflatex, lualatex, xelatex, latex+dvips+ps2pdf

\begin{document}

%same interface as ocg.sty, ocg-p.sty, ocgx.sty
\begin{ocg}{hello}{hello}{1}
  \strut Hello!
\end{ocg}
\begin{ocg}{good bye}{good bye}{0}
  \strut Good bye!
\end{ocg}

\toggleocgs{hello {good bye}}{\fbox{Toggle visibility}} %ocg-p
%\switchocg{hello {good bye}}{\fbox{Toggle visibility}} %ocgx

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good to know, I missed this new package. It is not contained on the TeXlive 2015-DVD - I will check it when I have access to update my TeX-installation.

Comment: I have problems to use ocgx2 as a drop in replacement.
ocg-p supports optional options in `\toggleocgs` (page 5 in documentation),
ocg-x supports no optional parameters in `\switchocg`.

If I add a `\renewcommand{\toggleocgs}[3][]{\switchocg{#2}{#3}}` my document is processed.

Comment: @knut Ok, I will look into it.

Comment: Accepted. The usage of the optional parameters in `toggleocgs` is no must in my document, I was able to use `\switchocg`..

Comment: @knut: The new version 0.8 of `ocgx2` is now online. It fully supports the one option (`triggerocg`) that `ocg-p` provides for its OCG setting commands.

Answer (score 10):

Quick help: Set the pdftexversion-number to the expected value.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\def\pdftexversion{120}
\usepackage{ocg-p}%Layers

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Background:

ocg-p makes the following checks:

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
[...]
\ifpdf
  \ifnum\pdftexversion<120
    \PackageError{ocg-p}{%
      pdfeTeX, version >= 1.20, required%
    }{%
       Install a newer version!%
    }%
  \fi
\else
  \ifxetex
     %already ok 
  \else
    % dvips
    \@ocgp@ifpstrue
    \PackageWarningNoLine{ocg-p}{%
      Only XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX are supported%
    }%
  \fi
\fi
```

In the past lualatex 79 set pdftexversion 200.
Since TeXlive 2015 the value is set to the value of lualatexversion (actually 80).
So this check fails and you get the error.

[In the future](http://iwww.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-June/036995.html) pdftexversion will not be defined.

---

In case somebody has a similar problem in another package.
The version check could be modified to:

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\RequirePackage{ifluatex}

%....

\ifluatex
  %already ok (tested with luatexversion ...)
\else
  \ifpdf
    \ifnum\pdftexversion<120
      \PackageError{ocg-p}{%
        pdfeTeX, version >= 1.20, required%
      }{%
         Install a newer version!%
      }%
    \fi
  \else
    \ifxetex
       %already ok 
    \else
      % dvips
      \@ocgp@ifpstrue
      \PackageWarningNoLine{ocg-p}{%
        Only XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX are supported%
      }%
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
```

Comment: Remark: I informed the author about this posting and provided a style change to support also lualatex.

Comment: Thanks!  This also solves the problem that `luatex` in TeX Live 2015 won’t accept the option `interpolate=true` with `\includegraphics`, which worked without complaint in 2014.