# interpolate with graphicx and beamer in luatex

Tags: beamer, graphics, luatex

In TeX Live 2015, using the `interpolate` option of `\includegraphics{...}` with `lualatex` causes an error unless one specifies `\pdftexversion` appropriately.  For example, following [Knut’s explanations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266768/7883) in a question on `ocg-p`, this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pdftexversion{200}
\usepackage{fontspec,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[interpolate]{steinlen_address_card}
% from http://www.steinlen.net/main.php?g2_itemId=3645 (but any .jpg or .png will do)
\end{document}
```

However, the solution does not work in the `beamer` class:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\def\pdftexversion{200}
\usepackage{fontspec,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics[interpolate]{steinlen_address_card}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
ERROR: Package keyval Error: No value specified for interpolate.

--- TeX said ---

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.7 \end{frame}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

If I type `interpolate=true` instead of just `interpolate`, the error message goes away, but in point of fact no interpolation occurs.

Why does `\def\pdftexversion{200}` not work with `beamer`, and is there another work-around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `beamer` class loads many packages, included `graphics`. As such, you need to act *before* loading the class.

```
\def\pdftexversion{200}
\documentclass{beamer}
```